# Change div background color on percentage of height

Tags: javascript, html, background

I'm making a website with a couple of divs under each other and a menu which sticks to the top. When you reach a new div, I want the background color of the menu to change. I already have this script;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var scroll_pos = 0;
  $(document).scroll(function() {
    scroll_pos = $(this).scrollTop();
    if(scroll_pos > 2280) {
      $("#menu").css('background-color', '#6FC6DF');
    } else {
      $("#menu").css('background-color', '#B4B4B4');
    }
  }
);
$(document).scroll(function() {
  scroll_pos = $(this).scrollTop();
  if(scroll_pos > 3220) {
    $("#menu").css('background-color', '#B4B4B4');
  }
});
```

This works fine, but now that I want to make the design responsive, I would like the background color to change on a percentage of the website. Is that possible?

Thanks!

Comment: The second div doesn't start on a specific number of pixels, it starts after 100% of the height of the screen. So how do I use % instead of pixels in that javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    var scroll_pos=$(document).scrollTop();
    var docHeight=$(document).height();
    var percent=(scroll_pos/docHeight);
    var red=Math.round(255*percent);
    $("body").css('background-color', 'rgba('+red+',0,0,1)');
}
);
```

An example how to make the document more red the lower you scroll.
You can also implement a function that maps the percent to a hex value you wish to display :)

Or if you wish to change depending on percent:

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    var scroll_pos=$(document).scrollTop();
    var docHeight=$(document).height();
    var percent=Math.round((scroll_pos/docHeight)*100);
    if (percent>33) 
         $("#menu").css('background-color', '#ff0000');
}
);
```

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work, is there anything I have to change about that script to make it work? Javascript noob here, as you can tell. ;)

Comment: Open your firebug/chromebug... (If you have it installed, it's usually   binded to F12), and check the javascript console to see what went wrong :)