# How can I force the download of unused CSS images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, preload

This is kind of a continuation of a [**QUESTION I ASKED YESTERDAY**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17586162/how-do-i-change-my-background-on-scroll-using-css) and an off-shoot of [**THIS QUESTION**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396909/are-unused-css-images-downloaded).

Basically, I am using jquery to change css background images on page scroll, however on first visit, when the background changes on scroll it only starts loading then and there making for a poor user experience.

I am using cache headers so that this only happens once, but still it would be nice if it didn't happen at all.

How can I load the second CSS image before the page scrolls to make the transition seamless?

I am only trying to load [this one image](http://robt.info/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/funny-kids-comic-animals_2.jpg) in the background, not preload all images on the page before display or anything...

Current code I am using...

**jquery**

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
var fromTopPx = 200; // distance to trigger
var scrolledFromtop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
if(scrolledFromtop > fromTopPx){
    jQuery('html').addClass('scrolled');
}else{
    jQuery('html').removeClass('scrolled');
}
});
```

**css**

```
html {
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
background-attachment: fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}

html {
background-image:url(http://robt.info/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/funny-kids-comic-animals.jpg);
}

html.scrolled {
background-image:url(http://robt.info/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/funny-kids-comic-animals_2.jpg);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://robt.info/about/) - Scroll to see in action.

Comment: I don't want to edit a link to your site, but the background-image for `html.scrolled` is 404'ing. The jsfiddle I referenced has the correct url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few options here:

1. Add a hidden element and add your image as a background; the browser will load it and is smart enough to know that it doesn't need to reload
2. What I would consider the cleaner way: load your second image behind the first one:

```css
html {
    background-image: url(http://robt.info/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/funny-kids-comic-animals.jpg),
                      url(http://robt.info/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/funny-kids-comic-animals_2.jpg);
}

html.scrolled {
    background-image:url(http://robt.info/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/funny-kids-comic-animals.jpg);
}
```

Comment: yeah. have used this method... so far no love... ??

Comment: Im hoping to keep the same style properties that are in the code part of the question... perfect full browser width background...

Comment: Does this not work for you: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sNA4z/). Are you sure the problem isn't with your `url()`?

Comment: By garrr... you've done it my friend! thank you! :) everything minus the height element... perfect!!  shall we be pals?

Answer (score 0):

On the left side add all your images and make all of them positioned absolutely

```
img{
    position :absolute;
    z-index:1;
   }
```

So all images will be loaded on windows load. And just change their z-index according to scroll.

Comment: testing now. will this still allow me to keep center center background positioning?

Answer (score 0):

One more option is there is to make ur images in a single sprite and display them by changing position..in this way u will save 1 extra http call itself. U can create image sprite with http://spritegen.website-performance.org/