# Change Image on Scroll Position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, skrollr

I would like to change an image on a certain scroll position. For example:

Scroll 100px show img1.jpg

Scroll 200px show img2.jpg

Scroll 300px show img3.jpg

[Here](http://www.epilog2014.de/) I found an example what I mean.

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I change my background on scroll using CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17586162/how-do-i-change-my-background-on-scroll-using-css)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `onScroll` event to listen for scrolling, check at what position the scrollbar  is and make the image change or whatever your heart desires. You can read more about onScroll event [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onscroll). A basic code will be something like this:

```
var onScrollHandler = function() {
  var newImageUrl = yourImageElement.src;
  var scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
  if (scrollTop > 100) {
     newImageUrl = "img1.jpg"
  }
  if (scrollTop > 200) {
     newImageUrl = "img2.jpg"
  }
  if (scrollTop > 300) {
     newImageUrl = "img3.jpg"
  }
  yourImageElement.src = newImageUrl;
};
object.addEventListener ("scroll", onScrollHandler);
```

Of course `yourImageElement` should be replaced with the image element you want to change.

If you have jQuery availble you can use the [`.scroll()`](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) method instead of the event listener and the [`.scrollTop()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/) to get the scrollbar position.

Also, you might want to look at some scroll/paralex libraries like [skrollr](http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/).

Answer (score 4):

```js
$(window).on("scroll touchmove", function() 
{
 if ($(document).scrollTop() >= $("#one").position().top && $(document).scrollTop() < $("#two").position().top  ) 
 {
  $('body').css('background-image', 'url(https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-Ivk46EkgQfk/WWjbo4TdJbI/AAAAAAAAFUo/gUD7JABklsIA1gWIr5LS1slyY4QuTMkEwCLcBGAs/s1600/gambar%2Bwallpaper%2Bmobil.jpg)')
    };
 if ($(document).scrollTop() >= $("#two").position().top && $(document).scrollTop() < $("#three").position().top)
 {
  $('body').css('background-image', 'url(https://i1.wp.com/cdn.catawiki.net/assets/marketing/uploads-files/45485-8bdcc8479f93d5a247ab844321b8b9d5e53c49a9-story_inline_image.jpg)')
    };
   if ($(document).scrollTop() >= $("#three").position().top && $(document).scrollTop() < $("#four").position().top ) 
   {
  $('body').css('background-image', 'url(https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/e1/7a/03/e17a0385726db90de1854177d4af2b4f.jpg)')
   };
   if ($(document).scrollTop() >= $("#four").position().top) 
   {
  $('body').css('background-image', 'url(https://www.wallpaperup.com/uploads/wallpapers/2015/02/13/621414/6fc33c3ae65a58f9bb137f5cf011aebc.jpg)')
   };
  
});
```

```css
*{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 }
.main{
 width:100%;
 height:100vh;
 background-image:url('https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-Ivk46EkgQfk/WWjbo4TdJbI/AAAAAAAAFUo/gUD7JABklsIA1gWIr5LS1slyY4QuTMkEwCLcBGAs/s1600/gambar%2Bwallpaper%2Bmobil.jpg');
 background-size:100% 100%;
 background-attachment:fixed;
 transition: 1000ms;
 }
section{
 width: 100%;
 min-height: 1px;
 }
.content{
 width:50%;
 min-height:1px;margin-top:10%;
 margin-left:10%;
 color:white;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body class='main'>
 <section id="one">
  <div class='content'>
   <h1 style='font-size:5vw;'>first heading</h1>
   <p style='font-size:3vw;' >description</p> 
  </div>
 </section>
 <section id="two" style='margin-top:100vh'>
  <div class='content'>
   <h1 style='font-size:5vw;'>second heading</h1>
   <p style='font-size:3vw;'>description</p> 
  </div>
 </section>
 <section id="three" style='margin-top:100vh' >
  <div class='content'>
   <h1 style='font-size:5vw;'>third heading</h1>
   <p style='font-size:3vw;'>description</p> 
  </div> 
 </section>
 <section id="four" style='margin-top:100vh' >
  <div class='content' style='margin-bottom:10%;'>
   <h1 style='font-size:5vw;'>fourth heading</h1>
   <p style='font-size:3vw;'>description</p> 
  </div>
 </section>
</body>
</html>
```

**documentation**

```
create a web folder first.
create a img sub folder  // place  all images into this folder
now create three files // in web folder
index.html 
css.css
js.js 

copy code given bellow and paste it.
save the program.
finally run the program
```

**click on this link to see the video :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V97wCVY_SrQ**

**visit our website for full documentation :https://nozzons.blogspot.com/**

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href='css.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
    <script src='js.js'></script> 
</head>
<body class='main'>
    <section id="one">
        <div class='content'>
            <h1 style='font-size:5vw;'>first heading</h1>
            <p style='font-size:3vw;' >description</p>  
        </div>
    </section>
    <section id="two" style='margin-top:100vh'>
        <div class='content'>
            <h1 style='font-size:5vw;'>second heading</h1>
            <p style='font-size:3vw;'>description</p>   
        </div>
    </section>
    <section id="three" style='margin-top:100vh' >
        <div class='content'>
            <h1 style='font-size:5vw;'>third heading</h1>
            <p style='font-size:3vw;'>description</p>   
        </div>  
    </section>
    <section id="four" style='margin-top:100vh' >
        <div class='content' style='margin-bottom:10%;'>
            <h1 style='font-size:5vw;'>fourth heading</h1>
            <p style='font-size:3vw;'>description</p>   
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

**css.css**

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
 }
.main{
    width:100%;
    height:100vh;
    background-image:url('img/img_one.jpg');
    background-size:100% 100%;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    transition: 1000ms;
    }
section{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 1px;
    }
.content{
    width:50%;
    min-height:1px;margin-top:10%;
    margin-left:10%;
    color:white;
    }
```

**js.js**

```
$(window).on("scroll touchmove", function() 
{
    if ($(document).scrollTop() >= $("#one").position().top && $(document).scrollTop() < $("#two").position().top  ) 
    {
        $('body').css('background-image', 'url(img/img_one.jpg)')
    };
    if ($(document).scrollTop() >= $("#two").position().top && $(document).scrollTop() < $("#three").position().top)
    {
        $('body').css('background-image', 'url(img/img_two.jpg)')
    };
   if ($(document).scrollTop() >= $("#three").position().top && $(document).scrollTop() < $("#four").position().top ) 
   {
        $('body').css('background-image', 'url(img/img_three.jpg)')
   };
   if ($(document).scrollTop() >= $("#four").position().top) 
   {
        $('body').css('background-image', 'url(img/img_four.jpg)')
   };

});
```

Answer (score 1):

So i am just answering this old thread because I was trying to implement the same thing on my website but i found it a bit difficult to implement it  so I made a function of my own , its a bit easier to implement and understand but a bit buggy, For instance: if the user use the scroll bar instead of scroll wheel of the mouse the image will not change , hope it helps you :

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    function f() {
      t1.src = "https://igu3ss.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/chess_king_4.jpg"
      t1.height = "319"
      t1.width = "330"
    }

    function f2() {
      t1.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d3/Chess_piece_-_Black_queen.JPG/130px-Chess_piece_-_Black_queen.JPG"
      t1.height = "319"
      t1.width = "330"
    }

    function f3() {
      t1.src = "https://asmoodle.asmadrid.org/blog/s16240/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2014/12/protourney_knight_black_400.jpg"
      t1.height = "244"
      t1.width = "330"
    }

    function f4() {
      t1.src = "https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/x/chess-knight-white-background-29811348.jpg"
      t1.height = "244"
      t1.width = "350"
    }

    function f5() {
      t1.src = "http://cdn.craftsy.com/upload/3703789/pattern/115774/full_7439_115774_ChessKnightMachineEmbroideryDesign_1.jpg"
      t1.height = "319"
      t1.width = "350"
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div align="center" style="position: fixed; z-index: 20; left:38.5%; top:200">
    <img src="no.png" height="319" width="330" name="t1">
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container" onmouseover="f3()" style="padding:0; margin:0; width:100%;">
    <img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2016/01/11/22/05/background-1134468_960_720.jpg" width="100%">
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="container" onmouseover="f4()" style="padding:0; margin:0; width:100%;">
    <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/lens-flare-abstract-backgound_21276999.jpg" width="100%">
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="container" onmouseover="f5()" style="padding:0; margin:0; width:100%;">
    <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/lens-flare-abstract-backgound_21276999.jpg" width="100%">
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="container" onmouseover="f()" style="padding:0; margin:0; width:100%;"></div>
</body></html>
```

Cheers!!
Ha[ppy] Coding.